# Set firefox profile with protractor

Tags: firefox, selenium, protractor

I want to run tests with Firefox/protractor with the cache feature disabled.
(Actually, I'm trying to prevent 304 HTTP responses).

There are multiple ways to do this:

- Disable the cache from the backend-side by droping Etag headers -> I can't modify the backend
- Drop the Etag header from the frontend-side -> I tried, it did not work
- Disable the cache from firefox: I just have to set the flag `network.http.use-cache` to false

Manually it works. I receive only 200 responses and it's great.
I want to be able to set this flag through protractor configuration. After some search I found out that I had to create a custom profile and set it in protractor this way (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities):

```
capabilities: {
   browserName: 'firefox',
   firefox_profile: 'support/firefox_profile'
 }
```

The problem is that the firefox profile is not considered. Is it the right option?
Do you have a better idea?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
As someone (suggested

```
capabilities: {
  prefs: {
    'config.http.use-cache': false
  }
}
```

It did not work - I checked in about:config, the flag was still enabled.
How do you know what options you can pass in the capabilities?

Comment: Sorry @alecxe, updating the topic deleted your response.

Comment: I've managed to set the firefox preference several weeks ago. I'm trying to find the way I did this. Will provide you with a solution in case I'll figure that out. The solution in the answer haven't worked - had to delete it, sorry.

Comment: Would you be okay with a chrome specific solution or firefox is a requirement?

Comment: Firefox is a requirement. How would you do it with Chrome?

Comment: Posted it as an answer. In case of `Firefox`, I'm afraid you are required to use `firefox_profile`. Though, I'm wondering if [`firefox-profile`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/firefox-profile) package can be used with protractor together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example of how to integrate firefox-profile with protractor: https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile

EDIT: For those upgrading to protractor >=1.6, the old way of doing this was broken because 'browser' can no longer return a promise. The demo has been updated.

Comment: This is great! Just don't forget to install the modules `q` and `firefox-profile`. Thank you!

Comment: Note: see [this issue](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/issues/26) on that same repo for a currently working example.