# Is it possible to add a addon to firefox under a protractor test?

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Does this possible to trigger the firefox with `foxyproxy` addon in protractor tests?

I added the addon `foxyproxy` in firefox and tried to run the protractor test case but its triggering the firefox without that addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`firefox-profile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firefox-profile) package and `addExtension()` function.

Here is the [HowTo](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) about how to start firefox with a specific firefox profile pre-created.

See also:

- [Set firefox profile with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873378/set-firefox-profile-with-protractor)